# Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{R}$, minimum polynomial on $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{R}$, $\beta = \alpha*\frac{-1 + i\sqrt{3}}{2}$. I want to answer the following questions:

1) What is the minimum $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}$?

2) Prove that the minimum polynomial of $\beta$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ is p(x) as well.

3) Is $q(x) = x^2 + \alpha x + \alpha^2$ the minimum polynomial of $\beta$ on $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$?

4) Is it true that:
$[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$, $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta) : \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] = 2$?

1) I choose p(x) = $x^3 - 2$, by Eisenstein criterion it is minimum.

2) I try $p(\beta)$ and I get $0$.

From now on I am stuck. Could someone give me some hints, and explain what $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]$ is? ( I know for example that $[\mathbb{C} : \mathbb{R}] = 2$ but I can't infer from that an explanation here.

Comment: 1. Eisenstein${}$?

Comment: Wow, I do not know why I did not think of it, edited. I think it works for 2) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) and 2) both follow directly from Eisenstein. 3) can be seen via substitution or quadratic formula + Eisenstein.

As for 4), I believe this notation $[A : B] = n$ means that any element of $A$ can be found as a root of a polynomial with coefficients in $B$ with degree $n$ (or less), and $n$ is minimal (so there exists $a\in A$ such that the minimum polynomial of $a$ over $B$ has degree $n$).

With these definitions, it is clear that 4) is true on all accounts by the answers to 1), 2), and 3), and the fact that $[A : A]=1$ and $[A\cup B: C] = \max([A:C],[B:C])$. This requires showing but should get you started.

Comment: You mean Eisenstein right? Not Einstein...